# Show $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\exp\left(\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}}\right) - 1\right)$ diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have a sum that is divergent, but I can't prove it.  Can somebody give me a hint how to get this?  It should be fairly elementary.

The sum is $$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \left(\exp\left(\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}}\right) - 1\right).$$

I'm not sure if there are more simple examples, but this sum is interesting because if we let $p_k = \exp\left(\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}}\right)$, then $\sum $ log$(p_k)$ converges while $\sum (p_k - 1)$ diverges, so the absolute convergence theorem for Weierstrass products can't be weakened.

Comment: I think it is not hard, maybe somewhat unpleasant to write out. Write the series for the exponential. The constant term vanishes. The next term gives a nice alternating series. The next term after that is harmonic series. The ones after don't add up to much,

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c$ has an unused variable $n$.

Comment: To Andre, it should not require anything close to that.  To user21820, changed n to k.

Comment: Well isn't André's answer as simple as you can get?

Comment: I don't know; I'm not an expert in aesthetics - nor do I know every proof of this problem.  But I would surmise that such a proof wouldn't be Adorno's favorite, that's for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the sum
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(e^{\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}}} - 1 - \frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}}\right)\tag{*1}$$
Since $\displaystyle\;\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}}$ converges by alternate series test, if the original sum converges, so does $(*1)$.

However, if one make a plot of $e^x - 1 - x$ for $|x| \le 1$, it is easy to see  $e^x - 1 - x \ge \frac{x^2}{3}$ for such $x$. This implies the partial sums for $(*1)$ diverges as least as fast as $\frac13\log N$. i.e
$$\sum_{k=1}^N \left(e^{\frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}}} - 1 - \frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k}}\right) \ge \frac13\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k} \ge \frac13\log N$$
As a result, the original sum cannot converge.

Comment: Ok thanks, this works!  I could not even fathom how to do the rearrangements necessary for the other 'proof' suggested, this is really helpful.  Why did you try subtracting away the alternating term?  Is there a motivation, or was it a "try it and hope" situation?

Comment: @JohnSamples by looking at expansion of the terms, you know the first term is alternating and converge, the second term is proportional $\frac{1}{k}$ and diverge logarithmically. The rest of the pieces are small enough and won't cause any problem. So I move the first term to LHS so that one can "concentrate" on bounding the remainder from below. This is one strategy of dealing problem. To break a chain, hit it hard on the weakest link.